# Robo3T version 1.4.3, is not running on windows 7

Tags: robo3t

a few weeks ago, i downloaded **robo3t 1.4.2** and it worked fine on windows 7 x64, and now download **robo3t 1.4.3** and it is not working (not launch at the first place). I searched to download older versions, but couldn't find any.

any idea where i can find older version of robo3t or a solution to run the current version on windows 7 x64?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is a link that all other versions of robo3t are available to download

https://github.com/Studio3T/robomongo/releases